# Invalid argument to unary operator (on character column)

Tags: r, data.table, rank

Say I have the below df

```
df <- data.table(group_id = c(1,1,2,2)
                 , week_no = c('2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04')
                 ); df

   group_id week_no
1:        1 2019-01
2:        1 2019-02
3:        2 2019-03
4:        2 2019-04
```

And a grouped `frank` works fine:

```
df[, dummy := frankv(week_no), group_id]; df

   group_id week_no dummy
1:        1 2019-01     1
2:        1 2019-02     2
3:        2 2019-03     1
4:        2 2019-04     2
```

However, if I wanted to rank in descending order:

```
df[, dummy := frankv(-date), group_id]; df
```

I get the error:

```
Error in -date : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I suppose it is to do with column `week_no`'s class being `character`. Is there a way around this other than ranking date in ascending order, then ranking the dummy column in descending order? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(data.table)

df[, dummy := frankv(week_no, order = -1L), group_id][]
#>    group_id week_no dummy
#> 1:        1 2019-01     2
#> 2:        1 2019-02     1
#> 3:        2 2019-03     2
#> 4:        2 2019-04     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes. I see. Thank you. So the syntax takes a hit.
What if I had multiple columns and had to make use of the `order` clause? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Glad I could help you. You weren't that far away. It's just that the order must be specified with the `order` argument in the `frankv()` function. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers

Comment: Just found this in `frank`'s doc
`order=c(1L, -1L)`
:)

Comment: Thank you very much for validating the answer. Yes, even if it's not always enough, it's always a good idea to refer to the help documents to try to fix the problems of code. Cheers